# Global function to convert minutes to hours in vue-cli

Tags: vuejs2

I want to convert time (in minutes) to hours.

I have a method for that in javascript:

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
  return `0${(this / 60) ^ 0}`.slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + (this % 60)).slice(-2);
};
```

While I am using this method outside the `vue instances`, this method works well like in the example shown below.

```js
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
  return `0${(this / 60) ^ 0}`.slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + (this % 60)).slice(-2);
};


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    html() {
      return `<span> <strong><i>${this.time.toHHMMSS()}</i></strong> Spent in Week 2</span>`
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      time: "121",
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="html()" />
</div>
```

But I am using the vue-cli, and want to use that method in the data. similar to the shown in the example.

But it's not working, while I used that before `export default {}` in the component or, I used as:

```
 export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
      Vue.prototype.toHHMMSS = function (object) {
        return false // dummy function for now to check if method works
      }
  }
}
```

I know of using the mixins for a similar purpose, but is there a way to make this work without the mixin?

Comment: like in the example, I added the method in the `main.js` file and it worked., the error was given by some other plugin that was used this method.

Comment: Why not just write a helper function?

Comment: can you help with some example?

Answer (score 0):

Puts the following code in a file named **helper.js** or whatever you want

```
export function toHHMMSS(time) {
  return `0${(this / 60) ^ 0}`.slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + (this % 60)).slice(-2);
};
```

Then in your vue file, use **import** below the tag of **<script>**

```
import * as Helper from "helper.js" // Note the file location
```

Now you can use the following code in your function

```
var formatedTime = Helper.toHHMMSS(this.time)
```